# Are there any good instructions to decrypt SSL traffic?

Tags: ssl, https

I want to see what personal information a flash application is sending back to its servers. Wireshark shows that the app is using SSL, so I'm trying to figure out how to decrypt the traffic between the app and the remote server. I found these instructions on Wireshark's site http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL, but they seemed to be incomplete and I couldn't get it to work. Has anybody had success accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.charlesproxy.com/

It works because [it acts as a man-in-the-middle](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) (and therefore, your browser will warn you as the root certificate isn't trusted).

[image]

Comment: It looks quite effective. Shame it's not free :) I generated a pkcs12 self-signed server certificate and needed to fix a jdk issue on Ubuntu: http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-636?focusedCommentId=20325&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-20325 Not bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the private key for the server with which the Flash application is communicating, and the Flash app is properly designed, you will not be able to decrypt the traffic.

The only chance you have is something malicious: spoofing a certificate for the site.  The certificate you produce will be invalid, so you'll have to manually add it to your browser/OS's trust store before loading the page.  Once you've done this, set up a transparent proxy and sniff away.